# Nsolve not doing anything

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

When I try to use Nsolve to solve for two variables it simply returns the input. What does this mean?

```
NSolve[{(1 - x)/x^2 == 2*1.2/Pi^2*5.5*10^(-10)*0.5^2*0.06/0.02*(2*Pi*T/(0.51*10^6))^(3/2)*Exp[13.6/T], 
  x*T^(3/2) == (Pi^2/(2*1.2))*67/(2*10^(-15)*5.5*10^(-10)*0.5^2*0.06/0.02*2.7^(3/2))}, {x, T}]
```

Comment: Thanks, have edited but it still gives the same problem.

Comment: Then `NSolve` probably can't solve those equations.  Try inserting `Reals` as the third argument to the call.

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with huge approximate decimal numbers so turn everything into exact rational
numbers

```
Simplify[{(1 - x)/x^2 == 2*(12/10)/Pi^2*(55/10)*10^(-10)*(5/10)^2*(6/100)/(2/100)*
  (2*Pi*T/((51/100)*10^6))^(3/2)*Exp[(136/10)/T], 
  x*T^(3/2) == (Pi^2/(2*(12/10)))*67/(2*10^(-15)*(55/10)*10^(-10)*(5/10)^2*
  (6/100)/(2/100)*(27/10)^(3/2))},x>0&&T>0]
```

returns

```
{(1 - x)/x^2 == (11*E^(68/(5*T))*Sqrt[3/(34*Pi)]*T^(3/2))/425000000000000000,
  24057*T^(3/2)*x == 33500000000000000000000000000*Sqrt[30]*Pi^2}
```

assume x>0 and T>0 and so from the second equation

```
x == 33500000000000000000000000000*Sqrt[30]*Pi^2/(24057*T^(3/2))
```

substitute to eliminate x from the first equation and

```
Simplify[(1 - (33500000000000000000000000000*Sqrt[30]*Pi^2/(24057*T^(3/2))))/
  (33500000000000000000000000000*Sqrt[30]*Pi^2/(24057*T^(3/2)))^2 ==
   2*(12/10)/Pi^2*(55/10)*10^(-10)*(5/10)^2*(6/100)/(2/100)* 
   (2*Pi*T/((51/100)*10^6))^(3/2)*Exp[(136/10)/T],T>0]
```

returns

```
33500000000000000000000000000*Sqrt[6]*Pi^2*(210681*Sqrt[5] + 
6700000000000*Sqrt[17]*E^(68/(5*T))*Pi^(3/2)) == 5068352817*T^(3/2)
```

then look at a Plot to estimate the location of a solution in T

```
Plot[33500000000000000000000000000*Sqrt[6]*Pi^2*(210681*Sqrt[5] + 
  6700000000000*Sqrt[17]*E^(68/(5*T))*Pi^(3/2)) - 5068352817*T^(3/2),{T,10^22,10^23}]
```

which shows there is a solution between T==8.4*10^22 and T==8.5*10^22

and thus a solution between x==3.092*10^-9 and x==3.0376*10^-9

Use FindRoot with bounding values to avoid more numerical issues

```
FindRoot[{(1 - x)/x^2 == 2*(12/10)/Pi^2*(55/10)*10^(-10)*(5/10)^2*(6/100)/(2/100)*
  (2*Pi*T/((51/100)*10^6))^(3/2)*Exp[(136/10)/T], 
  x*T^(3/2) == (Pi^2/(2*(12/10)))*67/(2*10^(-15)*(55/10)*10^(-10)*(5/10)^2*
  (6/100)/(2/100)*(27/10)^(3/2))},
  {{x,3092*10^-12,30376*10^-13},{T,84*10^21,85*10^21}},WorkingPrecision->32]
```

which returns

```
{x -> 3.0625719427168463423734410827584827274789818044761`32.*^-9, 
 T -> 8.45379297284849685875884058676955508420831`32.*^22}
```

then

```
{(1 - x)/x^2==2*(12/10)/Pi^2*(55/10)*10^(-10)*(5/10)^2*(6/100)/(2/100)*
  (2*Pi*T/((51/100)*10^6))^(3/2)*Exp[(136/10)/T], 
 x*T^(3/2)==(Pi^2/(2*(12/10)))*67/(2*10^(-15)*(55/10)*10^(-10)*(5/10)^2*
  (6/100)/(2/100)*(27/10)^(3/2))}/.
{x -> 3.0625719427168463423734410827584827274789818044761`32.*^-9,
 T -> 8.45379297284849685875884058676955508420831`32.*^22}
```

returns

```
{True,True}
```

Check every step of this to make certain that I have made no mistakes.